# Can you perform "lookup" in workflows between lists in different sites

Tags: 2013, workflow

I am trying to perform a lookup to link two different forms together, and am struggling because i can only see lists within the same area of the site.  The other list is in a different area or SharePoint and i cannot find a way to perform this lookup.

Can it be done, if so how?

Comment: Sad to get that answer, I will try and muddle through the call http web service and see how i get on.
Thanks for your help/input. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not easily, but it can be done. The general answer in 2013 workflows is that most anything can be done if you're willing to work with the call http service action. One walkthough is [here](https://zareensoomro.wordpress.com/2015/07/02/get-items-from-sharepoint-list-using-call-http-web-service-action-sharepoint-designer-2013/), but again, be aware that this is not a simple thing to set up.

Answer (score 2):

Afraid not - workflows are scoped to a site (or a given list within a site), and therefore can only see items within that site scope.